# How can I retain cells in suspension for comparative microscopy?

Tags: cell-biology, microscopy

I am working on a [digital holographic microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_holographic_microscopy). I would like to compare its imaging properties with an actual phase contrast light microscope. My aim is to do this cell by cell, creating a z-stack that shows the same cells in suspension, in a volume with approx. 1-2mm side length. In order to do this, I need to fix each cell firmly in one XYZ position to be able to move them between microscopes.

I am not a trained biologist and I am wondering if there is known procedures/agents to do this. Here's a couple of (non-)requirements I could think of so far:

- the cells don't need to live through the process
- they should however retain their form for at least couple of minutes (acquisition time)
- the agent should be close to translucent and not form bubbles

Comment: you can embed the cells in a matrix. You can use agarose, geltrex or fibronectin. I am not sure about their optical properties though.

Comment: @alec_djinn Thank you. Someone has pointed me to low-melting-point agarose before.. 600 EUR for 50g though, what in the name of God..

Comment: You can use normal agarose as well, it is much cheaper. A 0.5% will do the job.